# Doctrine / Symfony 3: Authenticating user with multiple passwords

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

Is it possible to have Symfony use doctrine entity manager for db authentication, if I have scenario where a single user has multiple rows in database, but with different passwords?

This is needed because we have a single support user used for the username, but passwords are unique to every developer.

Comment: I think you should consider giving each developer their own username.  To identify them, you could prefix the usernames with some string, such as dev.joe

Comment: I assume you could do it with a custom user provider that found all users with a username and then try to match the password with each user in series to see if any matched. It does seem like it would make more sense to separate the users entirely and then just display a fake "username" on the frontend.

Comment: Yes, this issue stems from migrating older project to symfony. At the moment, I'm also thinking that the users should have a unique id field to match the username/email.  

However, I would still be interested to know if this is solvable with symfony & doctrine. Just to see how it could be implemented (if at all).

Comment: The standard user provider and password encoder workflow really only works on one user at a time.  You might be able to do it using the guard authenticator: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/guard-authentication.html.  Not sure.  Otherwise you would need you own full fledged authentication manager: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html